# How to respond requests with the windows host file?

Tags: c, windows, scripting, vbscript, windows-xp

Using the windows host file located in

> windows/system32/drivers/etc/host

Is it possible to respond a request from an application like when it is offline(not connected to the Internet)? Could you please give an example of this is done.

Comment: can you be more specific in what you want to simulate? What is offline and who is going to reply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to map your local development environment to a domain name, you can edit the domain name in hosts file and map it to 127.0.0.1, which is the loopback address.

That way, any requests done to that particular domain will fallback to your local machine.

You can also assign different LAN/WAN IP addresses.

When your development phase is done, you can remove the entry.

I would not recommend doing so, stick with the localhost and just make use of that to test virtualhosts setup or some sort of domain based configurations.

If there is anything else I can answer, please don't hesitate to post further comments on my answer.

Comment: "That way, any requests done to that particular domain will fallback to your local machine."  Lets say the application is expecting some strings back e.g. username and email address. Could i edit the host file to provide this data in the form of a string or integer. username: john doe, email:somewhere@cyberspace?

Comment: You will need a webserver, and a scripting language to process parameters.

I suggest you reading about GET and POST params.

Answer (score 1):

The *hosts* file only lists *aliases* for ip-addresses. For example:

```
192.168.0.1     foo bar foo.com bar.com
```

If that line is in the *hosts* file, then you can use the host-names *foo*, *bar*, *foo.com* and *bar.com* to reach the computer with ip-address 192.168.0.1.

If the computer, or the service you want to reach on that address, is not online, you can't reach it no matter what you have in your *hosts* file.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to respond *to HTTP requests* then you need a Web Server configured to respond to any host (or that specific host name) on port 80. If you are not using it for anything else IIS can do this<sup>1</sup> – configure it to return 404 (not found) or some other relatively neutral fail response.

---

<sup>1</sup> If IIS is already being used then things get much harder, later versions of IIS are more flexible either with a combination of using HTTP.SYS to allow other applications to respond to certain URLs or using different Web Sites in IIS (until Windows 7, or maybe Vista, only available on Server editions of Windows).

Comment: Say for instance i have a test windows application on my desktop and it makes a post to a webpage. Cant I input the ip and address into the host file and host name and reply with some text to serve to the application?

Comment: @megatr0n Yes, if you have an application running locally that takes those text files and uses them to respond to requests – if the protocol is HTTP (see comment on Q: we need more specific information) then that application is a *Web Server*.